# How to get geolocation in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am building app in phonegap.I want my app to ask for turning gps on of device(IOS/ANDROID/WINDOWS) and then alert the current latitude and longitude. Can anyone please guide me how can i do it.I have tried this

```
   function locate(){
    alert("enter");

    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 3000 });
    alert(watchID);
}   
function onSuccess(position) {

    alert(position.coords.latitude); 
                       alert(position.coords.longitude); 

}


function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

but this goes in onError block with error.code=3 and error.message=timeout and watchId=4 Please help..

Comment: [GPS is Unreliable](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki/GPSisUnreliable.md)

Comment: so what should i use?

Comment: That depends on your plans for GPS. The articles listed point to several instances of GPS failure. The last section (*Sources of GPS signal errors*) shows you the technical reason; for instance: \*Signal multipath\* - *This occurs when the GPS signal is reflected off objects such as tall buildings or large rock surfaces before it reaches the receiver. This increases the travel time of the signal, thereby causing errors.* So in this case, it is obvious you should be aware when you are near _tall buildings or large rock surfaces_ that those things may cause an error. Avoid those things or adjust

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually including the geolocation plugin here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Also make sure you are not calling your locate() function until after the deviceready event has fired.

Your timeout is a bit low and may be causing problems as well if the lock cannot be obtained in that time.  I would set the timeout no less than 10 seconds (10000).  You may want to set the maximum age to 3000 to get the effect you want.  Also most people would want enableHighAccuracy set to true as well.